# How to get multiuser value from the Instagram API?

Tags: php, instagram-api

How to get Multiple ids data in single api query Instagram? I have some bunch of Instagram ids. Using that, how to get all the users feed from, a with single api query?

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/510338836,18428658
```

Comment: and where is your code ?

Comment: That is ok, but please give more effort into the writing quality. Anybody knowing here enough to give you answers, has practically always very good writing quality.

Comment: you cannot pass  multiple `ids`, you have to do one by one